# overloading function IN ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net, function, overloading

I have a function name "Fill" that contains 7 parameters. When I call "Fill" with 7 parameters it is okay, but when I call only 5 or 6 parameters it error (No overloaded for method "Fill" take ..arguments). I need to call this function many times.

```
private void Fill(string val1,string val2,string val3, string val4, string val5, string val6,string val7)
{ 
      //code 
} 
protected void Add1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
      --------- 
      Fill("val1","val2","val3","val4","val5","val6","val7") 
} 
protected void Add2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
      --------- 
      Fill("val1","val2","val3","val4","val5","val6") 
}
```

Comment: Some code please !

Comment: private void Fill(string val1,string val2,string val3, string val4, string val5, string val6,string val7){
//code
}


protected void Add1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
---------
Fill("val1","val2","val3","val4","val5","val6","val7")
}



protected void Add2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
---------
Fill("val1","val2","val3","val4","val5","val6")
}

Comment: either add some default values, either also make the other function with less parameters as well...

Comment: I would recommend to read about method's overloading firstly!

Comment: Thank for ur recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to pass a params array into the function rather than individual arguments. For example:

```
private void Fill(params string[] values) 
{
    // Code
}
```

You can then call it with any number of parameters you need:

```
Fill("val1");
Fill("val1", "val2", "val3");
Fill("val1","val2","val3","val4","val5","val6","val7");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can overload the method by creating another method with the same name, but different parameters.  Example

```
public int Add(int a, int b, int c)

public int Add(int a, int b)

public int Add(int a, int b, int c, int d)
```

Or, you can use defaults:

public int Add(int a, int b=9, int c=10)

Comment: Do I have to create another function with the same name? Anyway that I can use only one function?

Comment: Yes, you would probably want to use the last example where all of your parameters (or as many as you like at the end of the parameter list) would be a default of a zero length string - "".